# Not able to create .plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

Using following code to create .plist file programmatically.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OfflineData.plist"]];
```

But when I check in Document Directory file, no file exists on the path.
Not able to understand why file is not created?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to write the plist

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: Thanks for your reply. I got an idea from your comment. Actually I store NSMutableArray to plist but the NSMutableArray value is somehow nil. so blank .plist file not created. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you write the data? Where do you read it?